# 9patch image and Android Studio build failing

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

I have an interesting issue, and I dont know how to handle it. 
So, until now everything was fine, I was able to build my project. I just replaced an image with it`s 9patch version in three different sizes(mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi).

```
tw.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tag_rotate)
```

This is the line, where the building failing. It`s interesing, because the studio is able to show me the image on the left, and it is NOT marked as red. But the build is failing with the following message:

```
Error:(196, 52) error: cannot find symbol variable tag_rotate
```

**UPDATE:**
if I remove the image from the code, and replace with a normal image, it works ! Im using the default 9patcher provided by SDK

Comment: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What kind of nine-patch generator do you use?
I recomend you to use [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) generator.
I tried to use standart android 9patch generator, which delivered with android SDK, and I had the problems with it.

Comment: your link is broken, I using the one which is provided by Android SDK

Comment: @Karoly, sorry for that. Try again

Comment: thx mate it`s worked !
One message for google android devs, when google indexing stackoverflow: Googlers, please fix your 9patch,takes valuable time from my life

Comment: Seriously!? android sdk default draw9patch is failing to generate a proper 9-patch image. Thanks Alexander. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a line on your imports that says `import android.R;`.

If there is,Delete the import and it should be fine.

Comment: nope, I can replace the image with another from my drawable.

Answer (score 0):

The Draw 9-patch tool is a WYSIWYG editor that allows you to create bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view and the size of the screen. Selected parts of the image are scaled horizontally or vertically based indicators drawn within the image.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

**Nine-patch generator**

https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg-history/9472134d092f3375aa9cf767d6a4b2eca561c0ba/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Comment: I clearly know what 9patch is, I taught Android Dev on university for 5 years, Please read my question first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are make online generator tools then Don't use the any special character for image name

Answer (score 0):

The 9 patch tool in android studio is automatically generating bad patches. 
You need to repatch till the red bad patches go away and the error should be fixed. To see bad patches just select the Show bad patches checkbox.